# Java using compareTo method but get different result by printing and returning boolean

Tags: java

I was trying to search by the following method but when I try to search by a String list and a string but it return true by print out but return false by return.

```
public Boolean Search(List<E> list, E e){
    if(list.size() == 1){
        //here
        System.out.println(list.get(0).compareTo(e)==0);
        return (list.get(0).compareTo(e) == 0);
    }
    if(list.get(list.size()/2).compareTo(e) == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        if(list.get(list.size()/2).compareTo(e) >0){
            Search(list.subList(list.size()/2-1,list.size()-1),e);
        }
        else{
            Search(list.subList(0,list.size()/2),e);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, and sounds as though you haven't done any debugging yet (or don't know how to). Please use these [complimentary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and then come back and create a [mcve] that explains any issues you're having with what you've discovered.

Comment: If you want to know if an certain object is in a list you can use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_indexof.htm

Comment: Also, it looks like you're searching the wrong sublists and can't​ find an element at the last position of the list or of any sublist. Please follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second half of your method, you just call `Search` recursively but discard the result. That's your error. Return the result of your recursive calls instead.

Comment: I have found the reason. It is indeed because of recursion. Thanks a lot.